# Ember.js sometimes not showing errors

Tags: ember.js

Sometimes the ember app crashes, normally when I do something at an earlier stage, but I haven't really seen a pattern - and no error is logged to the console.

I can see the error if I set a break point to `TRY_CATCH_ERROR.error = e;` somewhere in the guts of the rendered app - but there has to be a simpler way I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All errors:

```
Ember.onerror = function(error) {
   console.log(error)
}
```

[Implement an Ember.onerror hook to log all errors in production](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/configuring-ember/debugging/#toc_implement-an-ember-onerror-hook-to-log-all-errors-in-production)

---

For Promises:

```
Ember.RSVP.on('error', function(error) {
  Ember.Logger.assert(false, error);
});
```

[Errors within an RSVP.Promise](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/configuring-ember/debugging/#toc_errors-within-an-code-rsvp-promise-code)

---

Run loop stack traces

```
Ember.run.backburner.DEBUG = true;
```

[Errors within Ember.run.later (Backburner.js)](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/configuring-ember/debugging/#toc_errors-within-code-ember-run-later-code-a-href-https-github-com-ebryn-backburner-js-backburner-js-a)

Comment: Where is the best place to put that code in an ember-cli app? As part of the environment config?

Answer (score 1):

I had an app which also swallowed the error logging; even adding the `Ember.onerror` function described by @Kingpin2k did not help.

After debugging I found the problem. I used the [error event](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_the-code-error-code-event) in my Application route to do some custom stuff if a 404 was thrown:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        error(e) {
            if (Ember.isArray(adapterError.errors) && adapterError.errors[0].status === '404') {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I forgot to add `return true` if above statement is not true. Forgetting such things practically removes the error logging, because the [bubble-event-chain](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/components/handling-events/) is broken.