# CLOSED Ember-cli : Error while processing route:

Tags: ember.js, model, routes, ember-data, ember-cli

I've got a problem to create a route to my model with ember.js. I've got the following messages:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/contacts 404 (Not Found)
Error while processing route: contacts'
```

This is my code :

```
// app/models/contacts.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  lastname: DS.attr('string'),
  firstname: DS.attr('string')
});


// app/routes/contacts.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('contact');
  }
});


// app/templates/application.hbs
<h2 id='title'>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
{{link-to 'Mes contacts' 'contacts'}}
{{outlet}}


// app/templates/contacts.hbs
<h3>Liste des contacts</h3>
{{outlet}}


// app/router.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('contacts');
});

export default Router;
```

These messages appear when I click in the link "Mes contacts".
I use Ember v1.8.1.

Someone could help me ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Your `{{link-to}}` doesn't seem right. Check http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/. For that to work it should be like this `{{#link-to "contacts"}} Mes contacts {{/link-to}}`. And also rename the model to singular `contact`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Link to is fine, it's non block form.  Model should be singular, but really the problem is you have nothing serving contacts at that endpoint.

Comment: My model is singular, I just made mistake when I wrote this post. But I don't understand what you mean by "I have nothing serving contacts a that point" ?

Comment: Do you have the ember inspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I start a new project and I don't have this problem.

But I don't know what I did wrong..

I close this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Ember Inspector if you haven't done already.  Then you can see the promises that are failing.

Also the normal browser Network inspector will show you the request payloads so you can see what is being sent and received.

Have you verified that the request actually goes to the server?

Have you verified that the server is able to precess the request?
(as it appears the server does not know the endpoint provided).

Have you verified that the server is sending a response with the expected payload?

Does the browser network inspector response payload show the expected result?

Comment: Yes, I've already installed Ember Inspector. When I clic on the link  "Mes contacts", here are some promises which are rejected : "Router: 'application.contacts': Resolve handler" -> "Router: 'application.contacts': Handle error" -> "Router: handle abort", "Router: Settle transition promise when transition is finalized" -> "Ember: Process errors from Router".

Comment: "Router: 'contacts' Model" -> "Router: 'contacts' Check if aborted in 'model' hook" -> "Router: 'contacts' After model" -> "Router: 'contacts' Check if aborted in 'afterModel' hook" -> "Router: 'contacts' Become resolved" -> "Router: 'application.contacts': Proceed".

Comment: Other thing : the name of my project is "ContactsApp".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Sometimes Ember is not showing the details of an error.

I ended putting a breakpoint in my vendor.js on the following line:

```
TRY_CATCH_ERROR.error = e;
```

I know you can also [enable more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915345/ember-js-sometimes-not-showing-errors) if needed but I haven't tried yet.

Bon courage! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with ember-cli when i've upgraded to the latest ember.js v1.8.1 with bower, so i downgraded ember to the version which is bundled with ember cli and it worked again.

I am new to ember.js, i find it hard to upgrade to latest version without breaking the app because of incompatibility with the generator and addons like ember-data.

Try using version bundled with ember-cli to see if it is an upgrade issue.